# jSLint with Angular causes Unexpected '$scope' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jslint

I'm receiving an "Unexpected '$scope'" error when I run jSLint against an Angular based app I am building.

Below is a reduced version of the code that is causing the error.  You can input the code into the [jslint.com](http://jslint.com) website to reproduce the problem.

I don't understand why the first function declaration (downloadFile) doesn't cause an error but the second does (buildFile).

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global angular */
angular.module('testApp')
    .controller('FileCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        "use strict";
        $scope.downloadFile = function () {
            window.location = '/path/to/file';
        }

        $scope.buildFile = function () {

        }
}]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lack of semicolons after the function is causing that error

```
$scope.downloadFile = function () {
    window.location = '/path/to/file';
}; //<-- add semicolon

$scope.buildFile = function () {

}; //<-- add semicolon
```

Comment: Thanks!  That makes more sense now.  It didn't cross my mind as jSLint typically tells you when it is expecting a semicolor.